`grad_2d` calculated but seems not used in Megatron-LM's cross_entropy implementation
In the implementation of cross_entropy in Megatron-LM (cross_entropy.py), we have the following backward function as
@staticmethod
def backward(ctx, grad_output):

    # Retreive tensors from the forward path.
    softmax, target_mask, masked_target_1d = ctx.saved_tensors
    label_smoothing, vocab_size = ctx.label_smoothing, ctx.vocab_size

    # All the inputs have softmax as thier gradient.
    grad_input = softmax
    # For simplicity, work with the 2D gradient.
    partition_vocab_size = softmax.size()[-1]
    grad_2d = grad_input.view(-1, partition_vocab_size)

    # Add the gradient from matching classes.
    arange_1d = torch.arange(start=0, end=grad_2d.size()[0], device=grad_2d.device)

    softmax_update = 1.0 - target_mask.view(-1).float()

    if label_smoothing > 0:
        smoothing = label_smoothing * vocab_size / (vocab_size - 1)
        grad_2d[arange_1d, masked_target_1d] -= (1.0 - smoothing) * softmax_update
        average_grad = 1 / vocab_size
        grad_2d[arange_1d, :] -= smoothing * average_grad
    else:
        grad_2d[arange_1d, masked_target_1d] -= softmax_update

    # Finally elementwise multiplication with the output gradients.
    grad_input.mul_(grad_output.unsqueeze(dim=-1))

    return grad_input, None, None

It seems that grad_2d is not used in the returned value.
Why we need to calculate it then?
I understand that the correct gradient should be softmax_i - 1 for token i, then why the returned value does not use it?
It seems we should use grad_2d as the correct gradient
